# Clearing ListView Data after click on other list view item

Tags: c#, listview

Working on application which shows some stats after chosing one item from another list view. 
As I observed that If I use `ListView.Clear()` then the view will be cleard - like repaint or smth, but once I will chose another index from "chosing list view" then this data from previous chosen `List View` will be added to the new one. 
My question is : How can I delete whole data except column names from previous chosen `list view` ?

Comment: Can you show your code? maybe use yourLV.DataSource = null;
yourLV.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `ListView.Items.Clear()` instead of `ListView.Clear()`, but [you are not alone with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ListView.Clear%28%29%20%5Bc%23%5D).